# JaCoCo report fails in Jenkins: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco, emma

I have been using JaCoCo locally with no problem.

When running a Jenkins job on a remote server, the job builds fine and generates JaCoCo coverage report (i.e. it appears in my `workspace/report` folder) but the build fails when attempting to publish the report on Jenkins.

I am using Jenkins 1.460 and JaCoCo 5.0.0.

I have configured Jenkins with:

- Path to exec files: `**/**.exec`
- Path to classes: `**/dist/validation/WEB-INF/classes`
- Path to source: `**/src` (I have also tried `**/Validation/src`, and explicitly including `**/**.class` and excluding other file types)

Is this a configuration problem, or a compatibility error?

[EDIT: In case it helps anyone else, other forums say JaCoCo requires ASM 5.+ to manage Java 8 class analysis. I am already using ASM 5.0.1.]

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 minutes 57 seconds
Archiving artifacts
Recording test results
[JaCoCo plugin] Collecting JaCoCo coverage data...
[JaCoCo plugin] **/**.exec;**/dist/validation/WEB-INF/classes;**/Validation/src; locations are configured
[JaCoCo plugin] Number of found exec files for pattern **/**.exec: 1
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched execfiles:  E:\Jenkins\jobs\Validation - Test Cases\workspace\Validation\jacoco.exec
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched class directories for class-pattern: **/dist/validation/WEB-INF/classes:  E:\Jenkins\jobs\Validation - Test Cases\workspace\Validation\dist\validation\WEB-INF\classes
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched source directories for source-pattern: **/Validation/src:  E:\Jenkins\jobs\Validation - Test Cases\workspace\Validation\src
[JaCoCo plugin] Loading inclusions files..
[JaCoCo plugin] inclusions: []
[JaCoCo plugin] exclusions: []
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoPublisher aborted due to exception
java.io.IOException: Error while analyzing class E:\Jenkins\jobs\Validation - Test Cases\builds\2015-02-23_15-59-44\jacoco\classes\org\gosh\validation\filters\ModifiedFileListFilter.class.
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzerError(Analyzer.java:150)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:144)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:175)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:208)
    at hudson.plugins.jacoco.ExecutionFileLoader.analyzeStructure(ExecutionFileLoader.java:126)
    at hudson.plugins.jacoco.ExecutionFileLoader.loadBundleCoverage(ExecutionFileLoader.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportDir.parse(JacocoReportDir.java:102)
    at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoBuildAction.loadRatios(JacocoBuildAction.java:291)
    at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoBuildAction.load(JacocoBuildAction.java:273)
    at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoPublisher.perform(JacocoPublisher.java:371)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:705)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:680)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:658)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:627)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1446)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at org.jacoco.core.internal.analysis.MethodAnalyzer.addProbe(MethodAnalyzer.java:288)
    at org.jacoco.core.internal.analysis.MethodAnalyzer.visitInsnWithProbe(MethodAnalyzer.java:224)
    at org.jacoco.core.internal.flow.MethodProbesAdapter.visitInsn(MethodProbesAdapter.java:76)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnNode.accept(InsnNode.java:80)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.accept(InsnList.java:162)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:815)
    at org.jacoco.core.internal.flow.ClassProbesAdapter$1.visitEnd(ClassProbesAdapter.java:124)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:107)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:142)
    ... 18 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

[UPDATE - solution]

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690840/2294676) I installed the recently released JaCoCo-0.7.4 (see [eclemma.org/jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/)) on my local drive. This version contains the fix for [issue 27088](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27088). I also had to delete and then reinstall the Jenkins JaCoCo plugin (I used the Jenkins Plugin Manager).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a compatibility problem between the JaCoCo version used during build and the version used by Jenkins in the post-build action.

The maven-jacoco-plugin version `0.7.3.201502191951` in combination with the Jenkins JaCoCo Plugin version `1.0.18` causes this problem. Version `0.7.2.201409121644` of the maven-jacoco-plugin appears to be compatible.

See also https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27088 and https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/pull/51

Comment: Thanks - would you please explain further how I could resolve this incompatibility? I have tried installing JaCoCo manually, and through Jenkins' Plugins Manager. The automatic installer gives me JaCoCo `1.0.18`, and all other modules (`org.jacoco.agent`, `jacoco-maven-plugin`, `org.jacoco.report` and `org.jacoco.core`) at version `0.7.1.201405082137` - actually a property called `${jacoco.version}`. How can I manage these dependencies?

Comment: Update - I have created a skeleton job which confirms that my versions of JaCoCo and Jenkins are compatible, so this is not the problem.

Comment: It only happens with certain Java code, likely varargs in methods cause this. As there is no updated Jenkins jacoco-plugin available yet, your best option is to downgrade JaCoCo in your project to a version before 0.7.3 or use a snapshot-build of the Jenkins plugin from https://jenkins.ci.cloudbees.com/job/plugins/job/jacoco-plugin/75/org.jenkins-ci.plugins$jacoco/

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried again, installing the recently released JaCoCo-0.7.4 (see http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco) on my local drive. This version contains the fix for issue #51 above. I also had to delete and then reinstall the Jenkins JaCoCo plugin (I used the Jenkins Plugin Manager). My report is now being published on Jenkins. I have a blank coverage graph, but I think that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
In your Jenkins project configuration for the JaCoCo Post-build action, make sure to set the Inclusions field. Something like  */*.class should work. Also remove the second asterix (*) from your expressions above. Make them */*.exec, */dist/, etc

I was having a similar similar ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception today from the Jacoco plugin, It only occurred in Jenkins though, not when running a maven build from the command line. Googling around suggested that the Jacoco plugin inclusion and exclusion field syntax causes people problems. I tried a couple different formats for those fields to no avail, so I moved to the cobertura plugin which was a cinch to use: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cobertura+Plugin#CoberturaPlugin-ConfiguringtheCoberturaPlugin

Comment: If you think _the Jacoco plugin sucks_, perhaps you could elaborate why? Note that I don't have any opinion about it, I just think such arguments should come with an explanation.

Comment: I have tried getting Cobertura to work for the last month, and I concluded in the end that Cobertura is still incompatible with Java 7+. I'm switching to JaCoCo for this reason. I can't find anything online to suggest that Cobertura has been updated, so unfortunately this option is not available for me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about explicit inclusions. I should have said that I have already tried including `**/**.class` and excluding (e.g.) `**/**.xsd`. The `**` works fine with other configuration settings, so I don't think that is causing an issue.

Comment: Googling led to threads that suggested that the ** could be causing a problem and that you need to enter values for the Inclusion and Exclusion fields. Once I did that, the Jacoco Jenkins Plugin stopped throwing the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception, so I thought I was on the right track, thats when I posted to your question. I was still having problems with it seeing my class files though, so I took a break and loaded up the Cobertura plugin, which worked almost instantly by simply adding it to my maven pom. Im building using Java 7 and Cobertura doesn't have a problem with it.

Comment: When you were using cobertura, what version were you using ? Im using 2.6. I think earlier versions than that didn't support java 7.

Comment: @Magnilex, I probably shouldn't have jumped straight to the "the Jenkins Jacoco plugin sucks". I've updated my answer to better reflect why I moved to cobertura.

Comment: @Sinsinator I think the most recent version is 2.0.3...? Not sure where you found a version 2.6.

Comment: @LydiaRalph, you're correct, Cobertura is at 2.0.3, I was talking about the maven plugin: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/2.6